# KineticJS drag a box with line connected

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I've seen an example of this done on the web before, but I cannot find the link anymore.

Basically it is a KineticJS example of a draggable box, with lines connected to it. When you move the box around the line will stay connected and redraw to the box's position.

I would really just like to know if anyone else has seen the example, or how this could be accomplished. I have googled the example, but I cannot find the answer anywhere.

Thanks.

Comment: [here](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-interactive-flower/) is an example. If anyone sees another one let me know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not too difficult to do...

Create your box:

```
 var box = new Kinetic.Rect({x:10,y:10, other stuff });
```

create your line:

```
 var line = new Kinetic.Line({ x: box.getX(), y: box.getY(), other stuff });
 var originalPoint = {x: box.getX(), y: box.getY()}; // save original box coordinates
```

then add a drag event redefine the line

```
 box.on('dragstart dragmove', function(){
     line.setPoints([originalPoint.x, originalPoint.y, box.getX(), box.getY() ]);
     layer.draw();  //redraw current layer
 });
```

like so: http://jsfiddle.net/KS9Bf/3/

This is exactly what you were asking about: http://jsfiddle.net/KS9Bf/6/

Its an update to the previous one.

Comment: Don't know what you were looking for exactly, but this is what I came up with, but with only one line.

Comment: basically, line.setPoints(  ... your points here ...  ) is what you'd want to re-create the line, and then layer.draw to make sure it is being redrawn.

Comment: trying to get something like [this](http://i49.tinypic.com/wan21f.png) to have lines that are all drawn separately. Thanks for your help thus far!

Comment: take a look at what the updated link above shows, pretty much exactly what you asked for above. thanks for selecting my answer, could you also vote it up when you get enough rep?

Comment: Edit: http://jsfiddle.net/KS9Bf/192/ you need to add the new version of kinetic in the external resources.