# KineticJS draw line between two shapes

Tags: kineticjs

I have two KineticJs rectangles that are draggable on the canvas. I want to be able to use some modifier (like clicking a button that says draw line, or a keyboard modifier like cntrl) and click on one of the rectangles, drag to anothe rectangle and have a simple line drawn connecting both rectangles). The line then needs to be linked to each rectangle so if either of the rectangles move, the line stays connected.

The second part of the question seems to be solved from this post: [KineticJS drag a box with line connected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14285235/kineticjs-drag-a-box-with-line-connected)

but I can't find any resources to help me with my first problem.

Comment: Do you have any code of what you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here’s how let the user select 2 rectangles by clicking on them**

You don’t even need a [start connect] button, just let the user click 2 rectangles and do the connection.

The user can select a rectangle by clicking on it.  The rectangle will then be highlighted with a black and red border.  The user can click that same rectangle again to unselect it (the highlighting is removed).

Highlighting is a separate rectangle that “outlines” the selected rectangle in a black and red border.  Highlighting is done on a separate layer.

[image]

First, add a couple of custom properties to every rectangle.

```
// isHighlighted is just an on/off flag
// to mark this rectangle as highlighted by the user.

      rect.isHighlighted=false;

// highlight is a second rectangle that “highlights” this rectangle

      rect.highlight=null;

// Add a click event that toggles highlighting on/off 
// whenever the user clicks on this rectangle

      rect.on("click",function(){
          highlight(this);
          target.draw();
      });
```

This function toggles the rectangle's highlight on/off when a user clicks it.

This function also tests if 2 rectangles are highlighted so you can connect them.

Yes...you found a good post on how to do the connecting:

[KineticJS drag a box with line connected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14285235/kineticjs-drag-a-box-with-line-connected)

```
// create a counter of highlighted rectangles
var highlightCount=0;

// when any rectangle is clicked, toggle its highlight on/off
function highlight(rect){
    if(rect.highlighted){
        rect.isHighlighted=false;
        rect.highlight.remove();
        highlightCount--;
    }else{
        var x=rect.getX()-8;
        var y=rect.getY()-8;
        var width=rect.getWidth()+16;
        var height=rect.getHeight()+16;
        var highlight=kRect(x,y,width,height,"red","black",3,target);
        rect.isHighlighted=true;
        rect.highlight=highlight;
        highlightCount++;

        // if 2 rectangles are highlighted, connect them
        if(highlightCount==2){
            var results="Connect these rectangles: ";
            var children=layer.getChildren();
            for(var i=0;i<children.length;i++){
                if(children[i].isHighlighted){
                    results+="["+i+"]";
                }
            }
            alert(results);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/MBPkn/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/kinetic-v4.3.3-beta.js"></script>

<style>
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 400,
        height: 400
    });
    // create a target layer where highlights are drawn
    var target = new Kinetic.Layer({name:"target"});
    stage.add(target);
    // create the regular layer
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer({name:"layer"});
    stage.add(layer);

    // create 4 rectangles
    var rect1=kRect(50,50,40,40,"lightgray","skyblue",6,layer);
    var rect2=kRect(125,125,40,40,"lightgray","skyblue",6,layer);
    var rect3=kRect(200,50,40,40,"lightgray","skyblue",6,layer);
    var rect5=kRect(275,125,40,40,"lightgray","skyblue",6,layer);

    // create a counter of highlighted rectangles
    var highlightCount=0;

    // when any rectangle is clicked, toggle its highlight on/off
    function highlight(rect){
        if(rect.highlighted){
            rect.isHighlighted=false;
            rect.highlight.remove();
            highlightCount--;
        }else{
            var x=rect.getX()-8;
            var y=rect.getY()-8;
            var width=rect.getWidth()+16;
            var height=rect.getHeight()+16;
            var highlight=kRect(x,y,width,height,"red","black",3,target);
            rect.isHighlighted=true;
            rect.highlight=highlight;
            highlightCount++;
            if(highlightCount==2){
                var results="Connect these rectangles: ";
                var children=layer.getChildren();
                for(var i=0;i<children.length;i++){
                    if(children[i].isHighlighted){
                        results+="["+i+"]";
                    }
                }
                alert(results);
            }
        }
    }


    // build the specified KineticJS Rectangle and add it to the stage
    function kRect(x,y,width,height,fill,stroke,strokewidth,layer){
      var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: x,
        y: y,
        width: width,
        height: height,
        fill: fill,
        stroke: stroke,
        strokeWidth: strokewidth
      });
      // if this is not a highlight, make it highlight-able
      if(layer.getName()!="target"){
          rect.isHighlighted=false;
          rect.highlight=null;
          rect.on("click",function(){
              highlight(this);
              target.draw();
          });
      }
      layer.add(rect);
      stage.draw();
      return(rect);
    }

}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is great thanks! I'm just trying to figure out how to use my own created Group of kineticjs shapes to use instead of your created rectangles. I have a button that creates a group (rect + text). I'm trying to turn the highlight and connect function into a button so when I press it I can click on my own groups.  Any idea how to do that? Do I need to include my group as a parameter in the highlight function?

Comment: I *think* I understand what you're asking.  So you want to highlight a group instead of a rectangle.  Should be easy.  The highlight is really just a rectangle that is behind and slightly larger than any object it's highlighting.  As long as the object you want to highlight has valid getX, getY, getWidth, and getHeight you should be able to feed your group object into the highlight function.  Be sure to add .isHighlighted, .highlight and the on-click event to each group, too.  See where the alert() is in the hightlight function?  You'll want to put your code that connects your 2 groups there.

Comment: Yep you understand exactly what I am looking for.  Would you mind taking a look at my code? When I put the click highlight function into my group, it doesn't draw anymore.

http://jsfiddle.net/MBPkn/2/