# How to draw line after click 2 images

Tags: javascript, canvas

i'm a beginner of javascript programmer, I have trouble adding images to canvas
the line will connect the two images that have been clicked ? I'm confused how to add images in accordance with the coordinates of the desired canvas ? Can I use the function kineticjs to add images and organize the coordinates ? Please help me
This is a html code to adding canvas and draw a line

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
canvas {
    border: 1px dashed rgb(200, 200, 200);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
<script src = "kinetic-v4.5.4.min.js"></script>
<script defer = "defer">
var clicks = 0;
var lastClick = [0, 0];
document.getElementById('canvas').addEventListener('click', drawLine, false);
function getCursorPosition(e) {
    var x;
    var y;

    if (e.pageX != undefined && e.pageY != undefined) {
        x = e.pageX;
        y = e.pageY;
    } else {
        x = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
      y = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }
    return [x, y];
}

function drawLine(e) {
    context = this.getContext('2d');

    x = getCursorPosition(e)[0] - this.offsetLeft;
    y = getCursorPosition(e)[1] - this.offsetTop;

    if (clicks != 1) {
        clicks++;
    } else {

        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(lastClick[0], lastClick[1]);
        context.lineTo(x, y, 6);
        context.strokeStyle = '#000000';
        context.stroke();
        clicks = 0;
    }

    lastClick = [x, y];
};
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use KineticJS to add images, lines and many more shapes.

You can also attach events (click, double-click, dragstart, dragmove, etc) to those shapes and perform actions according to their coordinates.

Take a look at this tutorial regarding
[Adding an image using KineticJS](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-image-tutorial/), and the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14285235/kineticjs-drag-a-box-with-line-connected) question.